Lock x-axis only in sculpt?
As shown in the picture, I don't want to mirror the mesh for the time being, and I encountered some problems when using sculpting: I want to lock the point on the x-axis (red edge)
Can this be done using geometry nodes or scripts?
Thanks！


Hello. Please avoid text written inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be readily found when searching in the future. Updates are difficult because it can't be easily edited in case of mistakes, nor updated in case of future changes. It doesn't follow the fonts and style of the website automatically, and doesn't work with screen readers.
